# spring cloud netflix - using EurekaClient without Jersey throws unrecognized field exception

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have an eureka server - [demo-eurekaserver](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/demo-eurekaserver) - and two registering services - [demo-eurekaclient](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/demo-eurekaclient) and [demo-feignclient](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/demo-feignclient) all using

- `spring-boot-starter-parent: 2.0.0.RELEASE`
- `spring-cloud version: Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`

One of the services (`demo-feignclient`) uses the eureka client dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and it registers fine.

The other service `demo-eurekaclient` uses the `EuerkaClient` dependency without jersey [as documented here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_eurekaclient_without_jersey)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

and it throws `Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo)`

here is the entire stacktrace

```
""2018-03-05 11:22:33 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8762/eureka/apps/"
""2018-03-05 11:22:33 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [application/json, application/json, application/*+json, application/*+json]
""2018-03-05 11:22:33 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8762/eureka/apps/" resulted in 200 (null)
""2018-03-05 11:22:33 [restartedMain] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Reading [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@548e8b]
""2018-03-05 11:22:33 [restartedMain] ERROR c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient - Request execution error
"org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.EurekaApplications] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo), not marked as ignorable (28 known properties: "port", "healthCheckUrl", "appGroupName", "sid", "instanceId", "countryId", "hostName", "isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer", "vipAddress", "securePort", "secureHealthCheckUrl", "overridden_status", "asgName", "app", "overriddenstatus", "leaseInfo", "dataCenterInfo", "secureVipAddress", "metadata", "status", "ipAddr", "is_dirty", "homePageUrl", "statusPageUrl", "lastUpdatedTimestamp", "lastDirtyTimestamp", "actionType", "status_without_dirty"])
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1184] (through reference chain: com.netflix.discovery.converters.jackson.builder.ApplicationsJacksonBuilder["application"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application["instance"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo["overriddenStatus"])
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:115) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:1008) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:991) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:732) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http.RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(RestTemplateEurekaHttpClient.java:137) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) [eureka-client-1.8.6.jar:1.8.6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:63) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:269) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2540b5ba.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2540b5ba$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$23d02a53.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2540b5ba.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:348) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:384) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:183) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) [spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:167) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:156) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:39) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:121) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:884) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo), not marked as ignorable; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo), not marked as ignorable (28 known properties: "port", "healthCheckUrl", "appGroupName", "sid", "instanceId", "countryId", "hostName", "isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer", "vipAddress", "securePort", "secureHealthCheckUrl", "overridden_status", "asgName", "app", "overriddenstatus", "leaseInfo", "dataCenterInfo", "secureVipAddress", "metadata", "status", "ipAddr", "is_dirty", "homePageUrl", "statusPageUrl", "lastUpdatedTimestamp", "lastDirtyTimestamp", "actionType", "status_without_dirty"])
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1184] (through reference chain: com.netflix.discovery.converters.jackson.builder.ApplicationsJacksonBuilder["application"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application["instance"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo["overriddenStatus"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:241) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "overriddenStatus" (class com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo), not marked as ignorable (28 known properties: "port", "healthCheckUrl", "appGroupName", "sid", "instanceId", "countryId", "hostName", "isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer", "vipAddress", "securePort", "secureHealthCheckUrl", "overridden_status", "asgName", "app", "overriddenstatus", "leaseInfo", "dataCenterInfo", "secureVipAddress", "metadata", "status", "ipAddr", "is_dirty", "homePageUrl", "statusPageUrl", "lastUpdatedTimestamp", "lastDirtyTimestamp", "actionType", "status_without_dirty"])
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1184] (through reference chain: com.netflix.discovery.converters.jackson.builder.ApplicationsJacksonBuilder["application"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.discovery.shared.Application["instance"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo["overriddenStatus"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperties(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1521) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:503) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1265) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:325) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:285) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:519) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeWithErrorWrapping(BeanDeserializer.java:527) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:416) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1265) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:325) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:285) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeSetAndReturn(MethodProperty.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:269) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BuilderBasedDeserializer.deserialize(BuilderBasedDeserializer.java:193) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._unwrapAndDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:4081) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3999) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.3.jar:2.9.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235) ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score -1):

If you follow up this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/ you will get to see the dependencies maintained by spring parent. Spring netflix is at 2.0.0.M7 as of now so you can switch to that. That should make the picture more clear, and then you can switch back to your own parent with selected dependency map.

Even though it may seem that jersey and jackson will collide, that isn't the case. So, drop the jersey exclusions. I was getting the same issue.

Also to avoid the pull of old jackson annotations do specify it... Current jacskon is at 2.9.4 but for some reason annotations will pull at 2.8.6. So specify both.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Versions used (sorry, these are all I need, you may need less):

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring-version>5.0.4.RELEASE</spring-version>
    <spring-boot-version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-boot-version>
    <spring-netflix-version>2.0.0.M7</spring-netflix-version>
    <junit-version>5.0.3</junit-version>
    <reactor-test-version>3.0.7.RELEASE</reactor-test-version>
    <reactor-netty-version>0.7.3.RELEASE</reactor-netty-version>
    <netty-all-version>4.1.21.Final</netty-all-version>
    <hibernate-validator-version>5.2.5.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
    <log4j-version>2.0.2</log4j-version>
    <javax-servlet-version>3.0.1</javax-servlet-version>
    <javax-el-version>3.0.1-b04</javax-el-version>
    <glassfish-el-version>3.0.1-b09</glassfish-el-version>
    <aspectj-version>1.8.13</aspectj-version>
    <commons-lang-version>3.7</commons-lang-version>
    <reactor-core-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</reactor-core-version>
    <jackson-version>2.9.4</jackson-version>
    <gson-version>2.8.2</gson-version>
</properties>
```

Below is my client pom that works (again, you can disregard webflux and its dep-s):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-netflix-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

With the following server pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-netflix-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${gson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer but the reason why I dropped the jersey dependencies from `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` is that I really have to use jersey 2 instead of jersey 1 imported by `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`. So I need an eureka client which is not dependent on jersey as documented here: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.3.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_eurekaclient_without_jersey